# Address Mismatch in Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am having some hard time in understanding the proper functionality of pointers to integers in C. In the Code-1, everything seems alright and apparently I thought I understand pointers. But in the code two the output worries me. As we all know, pointers store the address of the variable they point to, then in the Code-2 why is the output of LINE-1 and LINE-2 different. **Why doesn't the value of pointer and address of variable matches in Code-2?**

Code-1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 4, *p;

    p = &x;             // adress of x becomes value of pointer p, referencing operator 
    printf("%p\n", p);  //LINE-1// value of pointer, it will be the address of variable 
    printf("%p\n", &x); //LINE-2// address of variable
    printf("%p\n", &p); //LINE-3// address of pointer
    printf("%d\n", *p); //LINE-4// value of variable to which pointer points, deferencing operator

    return 0;
}
```

Output of Code 1:-

```
0x7ffe97df9fec
0x7ffe97df9fec
0x7ffe97df9ff0
4
```

Code-2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 4, *p;

     *p = x;             // 
     printf("%p\n", p);  //LINE-1// value of pointer, it will be the address of variable 
     printf("%p\n", &x); //LINE-2// address of variable
     printf("%p\n", &p); //LINE-3// address of pointer
     printf("%d\n", *p); //LINE-4// value of variable to which pointer points, dereferencing operator

     return 0;
}
```

Output of code 2:-

```
0x7ffd370c17d0
0x7ffd370c16dc
0x7ffd370c16e0
4
```

Comment: The behaviour of code 2 is undefined, you're dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In “code 2,” `p` is never assigned a value.

Therefore, it is generally unknown what `*p = x` will do. This expression normally stores the value of `x` in the place pointed to by `p`. But because `p` was never assigned a value, we do not know where `p` points, or if it points anywhere at all, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

When you printed `p` while it had not been assigned a value, the program might have printed whatever happened to be in the memory that was assigned for `p` to use, or it might have printed garbage obtained from whatever happened to be in some processor register, or something else—whatever happens is essentially just an idiosyncrasy of the compiler, not defined behavior.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. I am just a noobie. Don't mind. 
How can one interpret the output of *p = &x. Is this also undefined in C standard.
I got output:-    0x7ffe46f00000
0x7ffe46efff0c
0x7ffe46efff10
1190133516

Comment: @Jitendra: If your compiler allows you to do `*p = &x` while `p` is declared as `int *p` (pointer to int) and `x` is declared as `int x` (simple int), then you should add more switches to your compilation command to turn on more warnings and errors and enforce language standards. Generally, a compiler should not allow you to assign the address of an int (`&x`) to an int (which `*p` is), unless you are using explicitly casts to say you really want to do that.

Comment: My gcc-5.4.0 did gave me a warning for *p = &x, but gave the output. Now with your help I understand the functionality better than before. Thank you very much for your time.